# Understanding Lorentz transformations as partial derivatives

Tags: special-relativity

I'm currently trying to get some understanding of Lorentz transforms for Special Relativity, especially boosts. At the bottom, I think they can be understood as a collection of all partial derivatives of the transformation, i.e.

$$ \Lambda^{\alpha'}_\alpha = \frac{\partial x^{\alpha'}}{\partial x^{\alpha}}$$
or in matrix form the original transformation is
$$ \begin{bmatrix}
\gamma & \gamma v\\
\gamma v& \gamma \\
\end{bmatrix}$$
Now my issue arrives if I take into account that the inverse is given by 
$$ \Lambda^{\beta}_{\beta'} = \eta_{\alpha'\beta'}\eta^{\alpha\beta}\Lambda^{\alpha'}_\alpha$$

or in matrix form the inverse is
$$\begin{bmatrix}
\gamma & -\gamma v\\
-\gamma v& \gamma \\
\end{bmatrix}$$
So, up to a factor of -1 for the off-diagonal entries, the matrix representation of the inverse will be the matrix representation of the original transformation. 
Now, for example the top left entry of both matrices is $\gamma$. According to the interpretation of the matrix entries as partial derivatives we can write
$$ \frac{\partial x^{0'}}{\partial x^{0}} = \gamma = \frac{\partial x^{0}}{\partial x^{0'}},$$

If I only look at the outer terms I would manipulate the equation as follows:

$$ \frac{\partial x^{0'}}{\partial x^{0}} = \frac{\partial x^{0}}{\partial x^{0'}}$$
$$\frac{\partial x^{0'}}{\partial x^{0}} = (\frac{\partial x^{0'}}{\partial x^{0}})^{-1}$$
$$(\frac{\partial x^{0'}}{\partial x^{0}})^2 = 1$$
This would mean that $\gamma$ can only be equal to $\pm 1$. Similar arguments can be made for the other entries in the matrices. However, gamma can clearly be different to those values. Where did I go wrong?

Basically, I am looking for a way to understand how the inverse is formed so easily by just raising/lowering the indices of the original transformation. Is there some other special property that the Lorentz transformations have regarding to this, other than preserving the Minowski metric tensor?

Comment: Write explicitly what are the variables being held constant in each partial derivative, and you will realise your mistake.

Answer (score 1):

You appear to be ignoring some minus signs when you take the inverse. You say

> If I interpret this correctly, this means that, up to a factor of -1 for the entries where just one of the indices is 0, the matrix representation of the inverse will be the matrix representation of the original transformation mirrored along the diagonal.

but the inverse of a boost $v$ in the $1$-direction is a boost $-v$

$$\begin{bmatrix}
\gamma & -\gamma v\\
-\gamma v& \gamma \\
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
\gamma & \gamma v\\
\gamma v& \gamma \\
\end{bmatrix} =
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0\\
0 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}$$

when you write (correctly)

$$ \Lambda^{\beta}_{\beta'} = \eta_{\alpha'\beta'}\eta^{\alpha\beta}\Lambda^{\alpha'}_\alpha$$

you haven't seen that this will bring minus signs (from $\eta$) into the off diagonal elements.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! I updated my question to include your remarks, though it doesn't fully explain what I was hoping to get an answer on. Hopefully the updates in the question can help.

Comment: Not really, you cannot ignore those minus signs, and you cannot do a matrix calculation with only the time component.

Comment: I see now. I didn't know that the inverse partial derivatives are related by matrix transforms, but taking into account the other derivatives it works out. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> $$\frac{\partial x^{0}}{\partial x^{0'}}=\frac{1}{(\frac{\partial x^{0'}}{\partial x^{0}})}$$

As Charles has pointed out in the comment, the above equality is incorrect.
The [reciprocal rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reciprocal_rule) doesn't apply here: ref. [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1744211/736222), [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1090097/736222), and [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/185012/736222) Math.SE answers.

Comment: Thanks for your help and the links, very helpful!